# jQuery unobtrusive validation min - max or zero

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-plugins

I have a form with 6 text fields. The validation is standard for 4 of them, with just and min / max value. However, for 2 of the fields, the value of a text field can be either 0 or between 2 values.

I can use min: x, and max: y, or range: [x,y], for the between 2 values part but there doesn't seem to be a way to say max: 0 || range [x,y].

As a work around I removed the validation for 2 fields from the jquery validation and written some custom validation for those 2 fields. The issue is when the form is submitted it is tied into the .net code and the custom validation isn't working properly. I can keep on adding custom code, but I was hoping there would be a simpler solution.

Edit:

Sorry , I will try to make it clearer. I have a html textbox and the value can either be 0 or anything between 100 and 1000. Using the asp.net jquery validation from microsoft (https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive), I can use the range values [100,1000] or the min: 100 and max:1000 validation. But what I need to do is:-

say the value is either 0 or min: 100 / max: 1000, 
or 
value 0 or range [100,1000]

Hopefully this clears up what I am hoping to do

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can use pattern in html5 and write custom pattern for your need. This link might help https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp